# How does one subtract 1 from a BigInt in Rust?

Tags: rust, biginteger

I'd like this program to compile and print `314158` when executed:

```
extern crate num;

use num::{BigInt, FromPrimitive, One};

fn main() {
    let p: BigInt = FromPrimitive::from_usize(314159).unwrap();
    let q: BigInt = p - One::one();
    println!("q = {}", q);
} // end main
```

The compiler error is:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `<num::BigInt as std::ops::Sub<_>>::Output == num::BigInt`
 --> src/main.rs:7:23
  |
7 |     let q: BigInt = p - One::one();
  |                       ^
```

Comment: `BigInt::one()` would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: @loganfsmyth That would be way smarter and less convoluted than my answer. May I suggest posting that as an answer?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Nah you should just add it to yours :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust follows an open world hypothesis when it comes to traits. It knows, based on your annotations, that `p` is `BigInt`. It also knows that `One::one()` has a type which implements `One`. So Rust is looking for a subtraction operator on `BigInt` which takes a `One`-like thing as an argument.

```
num::BigInt as std::ops::Sub<Foo>>
```

where `Foo` implements `One`. Trouble is, `BigInt` implements `Sub` [in several different ways](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/struct.BigInt.html#implementations), so Rust doesn't know whether you're trying to subtract a `i32`, a `u64`, or another `BigInt` from `p`.

One answer is to be more explicit with your types.

```
let p: BigInt = FromPrimitive::from_usize(314159).unwrap();
let one: BigInt = One::one();
let q: BigInt = p - one;
```

However, more succinctly, you may take advantage of the fact that `BigInt` implements `One` and help the compiler with type inference that way.

```
let p: BigInt = FromPrimitive::from_usize(314159).unwrap();
let q: BigInt = p - BigInt::one();
```

(Thanks, @loganfsmyth, for this latter solution!)

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping that there was a more succinct way than declaring `one` as your solution does.

Comment: I'm still somewhat new to Rust myself, to be entirely honest, so I don't know all of the ins and outs. I'm a Haskeller by trade, so I approached this from a type-resolution perspective.

Comment: The types are redundant. `let p = BigInt::from_usize(314159).unwrap(); let q = p - BigInt::one();`.