# Why does type inference not work during addition when it does during assignment

Tags: rust, type-inference

I'm making an app using the rust_decimal crate.  Part of my app involves operations where the value '1' is an operand, so I tried using num_traits::identities::one() and ran into some unexpected errors:

```
use rust_decimal::Decimal;
use num_traits::identities::*;

fn foo(val : Decimal) {
    let _1 = one(); // E0282, expected
    let _one : Decimal = one(); // Ok, expected
    let add : Decimal = one() + val; // E0283, unexpected
    let inc : Decimal = val + one(); // E0284, unexpected
}
```

I am surprised that the compiler cannot figure out what type one() is meant to return in the last two lines.  Why is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one subtract 1 from a BigInt in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371674/how-does-one-subtract-1-from-a-bigint-in-rust)

Comment: Summary: there may be many types that implement `Add<Decimal, Output = Decimal>` and the compiler will not choose one. To fix it, the easiest thing is probably to use the turbofish: `let add = one::<Decimal>() + val` (the `: Decimal` annotation on `add` is not necessary because the `Add` implementation unambiguously determines the `Output` type.)

Comment: Is there a way to get the compiler to show what it's unable to choose between?  Decimal only allows additions with other Decimals (otherwise I'd be using a literal '1' instead), so I'm not sure what the ambiguity is in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one type¹ that can be *assigned* to a `Decimal` — `Decimal` itself — but there may be any number of types that can be *added* to a `Decimal`.

```
let add: Decimal = one() + val;
```

`one()` must be of *some* type that implements `Add<Decimal, Output = Decimal>`. But there could be many types that satisfy that constraint, and the compiler will not choose one, so you get an error.

```
let inc: Decimal = val + one();
```

In this case, if `one()` is of type `T`, `Decimal` must implement `Add<T, Output = Decimal>`. But again, there could be many `T`s that satisfy this constraint, and the compiler will not choose one.

To fix either error, you can explicitly say that you want the `Decimal` version of `one`:

```
let add = one::<Decimal>() + val;
```

(The `: Decimal` annotation on `add` is no longer necessary because the `Add` implementation unambiguously determines the `Output` type.)

> Decimal only allows additions with other Decimals (otherwise I'd be using a literal '1' instead), so I'm not sure what the ambiguity is in this particular case.

It doesn't actually matter how many types *exist* that satisfy the requirements. The compiler does not "go looking" for types to satisfy all the constraints; the types have to be unambiguously determined by only local information. Suppose there was only one type that worked, but it was defined in a third-party crate; should the compiler know about it? Or if there's only one type that works *today*, but tomorrow you include a new crate and there are two such types — should your code break then? It's to avoid this kind of nonlocal breakage that Rust declines to *choose* a type for you. In general², the compiler will only *deduce* types; it doesn't speculate.

This question is a lot like [How does one subtract 1 from a BigInt in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371674/how-does-one-subtract-1-from-a-bigint-in-rust)

---

¹Okay, this is not strictly true. Types that can be *coerced* to `Decimal` can also be assigned to `Decimal` variables. But coercion is only possible when the compiler knows both sides of the assignment already, so you can't infer through the `=` when a coercion is happening.

²There are limited contexts in which the compiler *can* choose types. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52692592/3650362) for one example. [Autoref-based stable specialization](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/blob/master/autoref-specialization/README.md) describes using a similar technique. I could not find a way to apply this to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is how Rust does operator overloading.
For an expression like `a+b`, Rust will first determine the type of `a`, lets say it has Type `T` and `b` has type `U`.
When `T` implements `Add<U, Output = V>` the addition can be compiled and the resulting type will be `V`.

I some circumstances the compiler can infer the Type of `a` by the context, but this in not the case in your example.

Because `one()` has multiple types which implement the `Add` Trait it cannot determine which Type `one()` should have. It could be that `f64` implements `Add<Decimal, Output=Decimal>`, which would make your expression ambiguous.

In the expression `val + one()` the type of the first operand is determined, but again there a multiple implementations of `Add` which could be applied: `Add<Decimal, Output=Decimal>`, `Add<f64, Output=Decimal`.

All of this can be solved by annotating `one()` like this: `one::<Decimal>()`. Which has an unambiguous Type.